# certain websites not secure now, two days ago they were

Tags: certificate-authority

i have attempted to go to a website that always showed trusted secured site, now i get warning. telling me not to use, because others can see my personal information. it only happens on accounts I have established

Comment: this looks like some legit attack. It could be some malware installed on PC. Some good antiviruses should find it. It could be also on your router, but less likely.

Comment: Can you show the errors you're getting and any certificate details?

Comment: receiving no error, no certificate details at all. just advising me not to open

Comment: A malware *installed on your PC* can easily trick you into opening the page without a certificate warning. Moreover, it can just open the site and perform actions there on your behalf without your consent and without you noticing. *Most likely*, not a malware.

Answer (score 3):

If a browser tells you the site can't be accessed in a secure way anymore, and you aren't completely sure you know the exact reason, then don't do it.

Most likely, it's just an error in the Web site configuration (e.g. a secure certificate has expired and a careless site admin just forgot to renew it) and it will be fixed soon (probably in no more than 1-2 business hours) so just make yourself a cup of coffee and wait for the site to go up.

Less likely but much more dangerous, a [man-in-the-middle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) sort of a malicious person is trying to steal your data or impersonate you on the respective Web site.

In both cases, it might be a good idea to call the Web site support if there's any and you somehow know its phone number.

*Somewhat* likely, it's just a [captive portal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal). Try to open http://example.com/, is there maybe a WiFi login page displayed? If so, log in and try to refresh the page.

Check also that your timezone and clock are correct.

Comment: What if the OP's clock was off?

Comment: Given the computer is connected to the Internet, odds are it's not. The idea was to enumerate *most frequent* reasons something is wrong with TLS/SSL (as there's also a hundred of least frequent ones), and it's hard to recall how old a personal system must be to lack NTP support turned on by default. Checking TZ is a good idea though.

Comment: To check captive portal, try another site _that doesn't have HSTS_ -- and for many people nowadays that excludes all sites they easily remember. If lacking any other, `http://neverssl.com` is good for this.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 http://example.com lacks HSTS support and is maintained by ICANN, which means it won't go away any soon. neverssl.com is registered to a private person and is paid till October, 2018. Hopefully the owner won't get bored by maintaining that, will be still in good health, etc. Clarified that in my answer, thanks.

Comment: @ximaera we have a number of questions here about this where the answer was simply that the clock was off. It's more common than you think.

Answer (score 1):

For the browser to issue a warning like that it sounds like a certificate problem. SSL certificates are how your device knows the server it's talking to belongs to the correct person. The site might not have changed anything - standards on what browsers will except continually get stricter. The odds are the site is still OK to use but not following best practices. Still - until you can determine why the warning is there I would be hesitant to enter anything personal.

First of all check if the page is loaded over HTTP or HTTPS. If there is a padlock in the address bar definitely  probably https.

Next if you expand the warning does it give you any more detail? I.e expired certificate? (if it's that they'll most likely realise and fix it within 48 hours), old algorithm?

If so please update your question with the explanation and I'll update this answer to expand. Alternatively update your question with the name of the website.